# Wrapping global variables in a class (python)

Tags: python, oop, global-variables

I'm new to programming, and have recently learned python and the basics of object oriented programming. I'm aware that having lots of global variables is generally a bad idea, and that I can put them all into a class instead. Is this the right way to do it?

```
class GameState(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1 = 1
        self.variable2 = 2
        self.list = [3, 4, 5]

g_state = GameState()
```

And, if I wish to access the variables within g_state, what is the best way to go about doing it?

Pass g_state into the functions/classes that need access?
Implement getters and call those?
Use g_state.variable1 directly?

Or is there a better way?

EDIT: To be more specific, I'm trying to write a game in python using pygame, and was thinking of putting my gamestate variables into a class so as to not have a bunch of global variables lying around. I'm unsure of how to access those variables with good design so I don't run into trouble later.

Comment: How many variables do you have? Are you running into naming conflicts? This feels so Javaeqsque...

Comment: I don't have that many variables yet, and can easily implement it using globals without naming conflicts or problems. But.. I was under the impression that using globals is not the way to go?

Comment: @user75909 I've added an edit to my post, but you must specify what is the usage of these variables, if you want any further help.

Comment: Thanks Rubens. I edited my main post to specify it's for a game. As for the individual variables, you got it right, so it's for stuff like incrementing the turn, using a potion, losing health and the like.

Answer (score 5):

You are right that too many global variables is not a good idea. Polluted global namespace may lead to errors.

However, **don't put them into class for the sake of it**. If you have really that many variables maybe you should consider splitting your program into multiple modules.

Also please understand that you can't really crate global variables in Python like you can in JavaScript. Your variables are always scoped under the module.

Let me illustrate with an example. Module a.py:

```
A = 42
```

Module b.py:

```
import a

print(A)
```

What do you get? `NameError`. Why? because variable A is not global, it is under module `a`. You need to use `a.A` to reference it.

There is no need to stuff variables under class. They are under modules, which acts as a namespace, and there is **nothing wrong** with it.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific on why I was trying to use a class. Edited my question to reflect that. I don't have too many variables at the moment and can easily implement it with module-scoped ones. but just want to avoid potential trouble later. So is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think you are searching solution to a non-problem.

Comment: I'm only doing this to avoid globals, which are largely agreed to be bad in OOP. Do you have a better solution in mind that doesn't involve classes?

Comment: Again, having 10 variables at module level is not bad and whoever regards this as a problem is wrong. You don't have a problem yet. Have you encountered any symptom?

Comment: I will definitely have more than 10 variables that my classes and functions will need to share, but that's not the issue. Though this particular game will be simple, I don't want to rely on programming habits that will restrict me in the future. At this level, I can also implement the whole game without going into classes or OOP at all; but my priority now is to learn how to do stuff, instead of getting a game up and running asap. It isn't a problem NOW, but that doesn't mean it's the best way to do things.

Comment: Then you have a different problem. You need to learn how to compose program with classes and define interactions between them. Sharing too much state can be a big problem. Perhaps you can post another question and we can help you design objects and their interactions. Classes are here so that you can split functionality into reasonable parts, not to act as variable containers.

Comment: I do know how to compose programs with classes. The thing is that there're some variables I don't want to include in classes. I don't want to load images in my sprite classes, for example, so it doesn't load every single time I create an instance of that class. Instead, I need to load (and store) the images somewhere else, and then pass the already loaded ones into my sprite classes when creating instances of those. I don't need to use classes specifically. I just want an alternative to globals. I mentioned using a class because it seems to be a common way of doing it from what I've read.

Comment: Well build yourself an image cache, that sprites can use. For game state variables its ok to have 1 top level class that contains main game loop and game properties.

Comment: Yes. My question was, what's the best way to access game properties within that class from other classes/functions.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to access the variables: one global object or passing an instance to a function. The first one is a bad idea too in general. The second one is better. But do not create a single object with all variables! (see the first comment).

There are more things to consider if you pass around an object. A good idea is implementing things as a member-function if suitable.

```
class VariableBox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1 = 1
        self.variable2 = 2
        self.list = [3, 4, 5]

    def do_something(self):
        self.variable1 = self.variable2 + 42
        return self.variable1
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a class simply for storing variables is not necessary. A class would only be needed if you really do need multiple instances of that class, each with unique values.

But for a single global state, a dictionary object can suffice for this purpose. You can store it in a module specifically intended for config and state if you want:

**conf.py**

```
GAME_STATE = {
    'level': 0,
    'score': 0,
    'misc': [1,2,3],
}
```

**main.py**

```
import conf

conf.GAME_STATE['score'] = 100
```

So your other modules can just import the `conf.py` module and access the state dict. You can store whatever types you need in this object. It also gives you a convenient location to add functionality for serializing these values out to disk if you want, and reading them back at future runs of the program, and to keep them alongside configuration options.

Comment: Don't you need `from conf import GAME_STATE` ?

Comment: @Kugel: Thanks. That was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

NO!!! Building a `VariableBox` will help you **NOT**!

Simply use the var you want, wherever it may applies. If you have too many global vars, it's rather a problem with what should be considered global, and what should pertain to specific structures. Or even a difficulty in naming the vars, or creating arrays, instead of `var1, var2, var3, ...`.

Classes are designed for building of objects, i. e., for creating things that differ for specificities, but have the same basis. A valuable class is something that somewhat defines an entity, and the main behaviors of this entity.

**EDIT**:

Python does not provide visibility constraints, so you won't be able to *protect* data by simply stuffing it into a class; the entries can be accessed from any place an instance of the class is.

Creating getters or simply maintaining an instance of a class is just a matter of deciding which one to work with. For the sake of maintaining things clear, it may be better to make a controller to your game, that will make this interface between game assets and gameplay.

For example, during execution, you could have:

```
class Controller:

    def __init__():
        self.turn = 0
        self. ...

    def begin():
        self.turn += 1
        self.opening_scene()

class Gameplay:

    def __init__(self, num_players, turn, ...):
        self.turn = turn # if it happens you want to use this value in the game
        self.num_player = num_players

# Main loop
controller = Controller()
controller.num_players = int(raw_input("Number of players: "))

gameplay = Gameplay(controller.num_players, controller.turn)
while True:

    if gameplay.action == ...:
    elif ...:
        ...
    elif *next turn*:
        controller.next_turn() # to set things up to next turn
    else ...:
        ...
```

Inside `Controller` you may aggregate correlated info, so you won't have an endless list of parameters in the upcoming functions.

Anyway, I'm not capable of telling you which is the best to use; there are lots of people that study these modularity issues, and I'm not one of them, so this is just my point of view on what could work out nice on your app.

Comment: I understand using classes like this, but that's not what I was asking. To be more specific, I'm trying to write a game in python using pygame, and was thinking of putting my variables into a class that tracks gamestates so as to not have a bunch of global variables lying around.

Comment: @user75909 Well, it seems you have a purpose then, and so it's totally feasible to have a class named `State`, that shall maintain info on specific details of the execution, and that may even provide some services, like returning the amount of players, the number of turns played, the number of attempts left, and so on.

Comment: VariableBox was just a placeholder name I used because my original post did not specify making a game, sorry :p Does your answer mean I should write a getter function for every variable? And should I pass an instance of GameInfo into functions every time I want to access a variable, and make the call from there? or make a single global GameInfo instance and then call the method?

Comment: or, instead of answering my volley of questions, can you write up an example of.. say.. increasing the number of turns using a separate function?

Comment: @user75909 I've added an edit, but, as I say in the post, I'm not qualified for modularity decisions. I simply use what best suits my applications, when I'm developing them.

Comment: Thanks Rubens. Even if you haven't directly answered the question, your last edit was the kind of thing I was looking for. I'd upvote you but it seems I lack the required rep. Will do so when I can!

Comment: @user75909 If the answer was what you were expecting, simply accept it as the answer; sorry if I did not went straight to what you were asking, but I needed the extra information you provided later (: As this seems to be your first question, to accept an answer, simply click on the `tick mark`, right below the voting arrows. Good luck with your game!